# Does UI-Grid support server side sorting?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Does UI-Grid support server side sorting? I could not find any doc on that specific topic. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like [this](https://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20307%20External%20Sorting). It uses external sorting for the grid in which you can do your requests with different params.